# Upgrade pyramid, SQLAlchemy, zope and rebuild Python project

Tags: python, ubuntu, sqlalchemy, installation, pyramid

I have inherited a Python REST API that runs on Ubuntu.

My main goal is to update these Python components to the latest releases, e.g. zope is now at 2.0.

It uses Python 2.7, Pyramid 1.4.1, zope 0.6, transaction 1.3, SQLAlchemy 0.7.9, WebError 0.10.3, and uses nginx as the web server.
Oh, and it uses cx_Oracle to connect to the Oracle instance.

The project (and other items) are in a folder called rest_api, where I can see setup.py, and some other custom setups, setup_prod.py, etc.

I went to /usr/local/lib/python-2.7/sites-packages and I tried running "pip install --upgrade [package_name]" and the command completes successfully for each package.

Is this all I need to do, or do I have to rebuild the project with setup*.py?

I found some notes that showed 2 commands that look like what I want -

```
rebuild_cmd = "cd %s/python/rest_api/; /usr/bin/env python setup_prod.py build" % current_dir
install_cmd = "cd %s/python/rest_api/; sudo /usr/bin/env python setup_prod.py install" % current_dir
```

...but when I try running "python setup_prod.py build" from the directory, with or without sudo, I get a traceback error.

To summarize -

1. How do I upgrade the python packages like zope, SQLAlchemy, Pyramids, etc. to the latest release?
2. Do I need to rebuild the project if I am only upgrading the python packages from above?
3. Without knowing the program details, is there a "basic" python build sequence that I can try, e.g. run setup.py build, then setup.py install, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

> It uses Python 2.7, Pyramid 1.4.1, zope 0.6, transaction 1.3, SQLAlchemy 0.7.9, WebError 0.10.3

How do you know this? Find the place where any of these versions are mentioned (I guess they should be mentioned somewhere in `setup_prod.py`), change them to what you want, build the project and check if the app works with new dependencies.

> ...but when I try running "python setup_prod.py build" from the directory, with or without sudo, I get a traceback error.

Please show your traceback.